# Wordpress: wp_hash_password not working as expected. All logins fail

Tags: wordpress

I have a process which creates users programmatically in Wordpress.

```
 $randomStr = generateRandomString(12);
 $pw = wp_hash_password($randomStr);
 $user_id = wp_create_user( $first_name . "." . $last_name, $pw, $the_email );
```

`$randomStr` works well, and produces results like `nUiR3B0eaCzd`. The user row is created correctly with the given e-mail and username.

However: The password hashes wrong. All logins with e-mail and randomStr used are rejected as wrong credentials.

what am I doing wrong?

internally, `wp_hash_password` uses `$wp_hasher = new PasswordHash(8, true);` should I use something else?

Comment: I think `wp_create_user` takes the actual password (not the password hash) as parameter.

Comment: I believe you're right. If you repeat this in an answer I'll be able to credit you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function `wp_create_user` takes the **actual password** as a parameter. You are passing a hashed password to it. That's why it is creating users with the wrong password.

Answer (score 1):

In Wordpress core file [wp-includes/user.php](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/4.9.8/src/wp-includes/user.php), `wp_create_user()` calls `wp_insert_user()` which actually itself uses `wp_hash_password()` to convert the plain, unhashed password you passed into `wp_create_user()`. To properly use `wp_create_user()`, you will need to pass into it an unhashed password.